# Transaction fees with Dogecoin or Ripple for small amounts

Tags: ripple, dogecoin

We are a company which sells low priced items online ($0.05 - $0.50). Due to the crypto currency hype, we also would like to accept payments through at least one crypto currency.

I have analyzed a couple of crypto currencies by their average transaction fees, market cap, avg. transaction confirmation, etc.

I found out that Dogecoin and Ripple have currently cheap fees, less than $0.01 cents **average**.

**Question**: Can we hire the company that integrates this in our E-Commerce backend or is there anything else important to know beside the exchange fees? Are our transactions too small?

So far I have taken following into account

- Transaction fees are not fixed, but as of writing this question the fees are acceptable for my case
- Exchange fees (mostly a bit higher since traded through BTC from USD/EUR)
- Average fees are less than $0.01, but theoretically they can be higher (if not average)

For most transactions I would assume the fees are <= $0.02. This would be okay for us, but which crypto currency should we choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully understanding where you come from, IHMO you should choose the crypto currency which most of your potential customers keep in their wallets anyway. Especially when it comes to small amounts (as you say) hardly anyone will be willing to go to an exchange first and trade 0.0005 BTC into a different coin only to pay you.

I would suggest to take a look at the Lightning Network (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_Network).

Comment: You need to understand that all this stuff is pretty beta; nevertheless, it works on the main network, i.e. with real world transactions. One kind of ready to use implementation for a kind of "crypto PayPal" seems to be https://strike.acinq.co/ though there maybe others.